# Chrome Dev Tools: See Changes from inspector in sources, with color markers

Tags: version-control, google-chrome-devtools

A couple years ago I remember I was able to see all my CSS and HTML changes highlighted in the sources, and it listed all the changes I made by line numbers.

But I can't seem to find this feature anymore. I know I can save the CSS file with the new changes But I would like to see all the changes marked,and which files I changed.

I found this picture from another question that shows what I'm talking about. 
[image: chrome inspector changes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI for this has changed a bit.

After you have modified an external stylesheet, right-click its resource in the Resources panel and choose `Local Modifications...` in the context menu that appears. You will see a drawer at the bottom of your DevTools window, containing a tree of revisions. Expand any revision to see its diff to the previous one, inline.

Comment: Dang that was a nice feature, well Local Modifications works just as well, thanks!